# kill only once instance of chrome from command line

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, taskkill

I have a batch file that runs to open a webpage in Chrome that runs a specific function.

```
start http://www.example.com/cgi/myprogram.exe
```

This process runs quickly, then I want to automatically close the browser window. I don't want to use *`taskkill /IM chrome.exe`* because Chrome has many services running under `"chrome.exe"` and I only want to kill the one that shows on the applications tag of task manager, not the processes tag.

Is that possible?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/306714/how-to-kill-one-tab-of-google-chrome-using-pid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just kill the new tab, you can use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "newPIDlist="
set "oldPIDlist=p"
::find old PIDs
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='chrome.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (set "oldPIDlist=!oldPIDlist!%%ap")
::start your site here
start http://www.example.com/cgi/myprogram.exe
::find new PIDs
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='chrome.exe'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (
if "!oldPIDlist:p%%ap=zz!"=="%oldPIDlist%" (set "newPIDlist=/PID %%a !newPIDlist!")
)
echo %newPIDlist%
::wait for page to load
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f %newPIDlist% /T > NUL 2>&1
```

However, note that this won't close the tab, it will just kill the process of the tab, causing an error message to pop up. As discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/306714/how-to-kill-one-tab-of-google-chrome-using-pid), closing a single google chrome tab from the command line is not possible.

Comment: I think there may be more than one tab per process as well sometimes, so this may have unexpected consequences.

Comment: You're right, however this is as far as I know the only reason to get the right one, as for instance `wmic process call create` doesn't give back the PID from Google Chrome.